# Matlab "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

Tags: matlab, trading

I keep getting this error:

> ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in ==> example3_6 at 48 results=regress(cl1(trainset),
>   cl2(trainset)); % use regression function

GDX file contains 7 columns and 386 rows, GLD file contains 7 columns and 765 rows, but if i'm taking a sample of 250 out of both this should not be a problem.

Can somebody advise what is the problem here?

Thank you

```
clear; % make sure previously defined variables are erased.

[num, txt]=xlsread('GLD'); % read a spreadsheet named "GLD.xls" into MATLAB. 

tday1=txt(2:end, 1); % the first column (starting from the second row) is the trading days in format mm/dd/yyyy.

tday1=datestr(datenum(tday1,'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyymmdd');

tday1=str2double(cellstr(tday1)); % convert the date strings first into cell arrays and then into numeric format.

adjcls1=num(:, end); % the last column contains the adjusted close prices.

[num, txt]=xlsread('GDX'); % read a spreadsheet named "GDX.xls" into MATLAB. 

tday2=txt(2:end, 1); % the first column (starting from the second row) is the trading days in format mm/dd/yyyy.

tday2=datestr(datenum(tday2,'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyymmdd');

tday2=str2double(cellstr(tday2)); % convert the date strings first into cell arrays and then into numeric format.

adjcls2=num(:, end); % the last column contains the adjusted close prices.

[tday, idx1, idx2]=intersect(tday1, tday2); % find the intersection of the two data sets, and sort them in ascending order

cl1=adjcls1(idx1); 

cl2=adjcls2(idx2);  

trainset=1:252; % define indices for training set

testset=trainset(end)+1:length(tday); % define indices for test set

% determines the hedge ratio on the trainset
results=ols(cl1(trainset), cl2(trainset)); % use regression function 
hedgeRatio=results.beta;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with your call to the regress function.

According to    doc regress:

regress(y,X) returns a p-by-1 vector b of coefficient estimates for a multilinear regression of the responses in y on the predictors in X. X is an n-by-p matrix of p predictors at each of n observations. y is an n-by-1 vector of observed responses.

But since we don't know how you use the regress function in your ols function, it's pretty hard to help you.  Just run a size(...) check on the two arguments you send to regress() and I'm sure you will find out why MATLAB is complaining.

Comment: i ran the size() function and this is what i get 

    size(cl1) ans = 2   1  
    size(trainset) ans = 1   252 

I'm sure the error is because i'm plugging a 1:252 vector into a 2:1 matrix, but how do i change the 2:1 matrix size to fit the vector in?  This is the first time i'm using matlab, so i'm not really familiar with it. Just using it to follow the book i'm reading.